# How to access data from a textview in a fragment Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello all so my mainActivity's layout for my app is just one huge fragment. I am planning on using shared preferences to determine which fragment I want to start first. everything is going great however I cannot access data from my fragments textview. It will show up as null. here is my main activity class

```
   SessionManager session;




   /**
    * The starting point of the app.
    * @param savedInstanceState
    */
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this,this);
       session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());




       if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
           FirstFragment frag = new FirstFragment();
           FragmentTransaction f = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           f.add(R.id.flFragment, frag);
           f.commit();
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, session.getUserDetails().get("name") + " is logged in ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       } else {
           LoginFragment frag = new LoginFragment();
           FragmentTransaction f = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           f.add(R.id.flFragment, frag);
           f.commit();
       }


   }


   /**
    * button onclick event listener
    * @param v
    */
   public void loginButton(View v) {
       LoginFragment frag = new LoginFragment();
       session.createLoginSession(frag.userName.getText().toString()); \\ null pointer happens here
   }
```

here is code from my LoginFragment class

```
    MaterialEditText userName, password;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        userName = view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        return view;
    }
```

I also tried to initialize userName in my mainActivitys onCreate with findviewbyId but it will still be null

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `loginButton()` method, you are creating a brand new instance of the LoginFragment, and it has no reference to the login fragment being displayed to the user. This is wrong.

Instead, you should place the handler for the login button click inside the actual LoginFragment like so:

```
public void loginButton(View v) {
       getActivity().getSession().createLoginSession(this.userName.getText().toString());
   }
```

This assumes that the button in the layout resource file includes `android:onClick="loginButton"`

Of course this would mean the Activity needs to create the getter method `getSession()` to return the session. This isn't ideal... you could pass the session as a constructor parameter to the Fragment which is cleaner.